# This query is for specific sports - what changes do I have to make for getting results of all sports and the top 3 alone in each of the sport

Tags: sql, sql-server

Individual sports ---- 30 day ----- Online users

```
SELECT RoomId, Name, 
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) 
            From ChatUserLog 
            WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId 
              AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, 
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) 
            From LoggedInUser 
            WHERE RoomID = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline 
From Room 
Where Sports = @Sports 
ORDER BY UserOnline DESC
```

Individual sports ---- 30 day ----- Total users

```
SELECT RoomId, Name, 
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) 
            From ChatUserLog 
            WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId 
              AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, 
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) 
            From LoggedInUser 
            WHERE RoomID = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline 
From Room 
Where Sports = @Sports 
ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

What changes do I have to make to the query for getting results of all sports and the top 3 alone in each of the sport?

The Table details are

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Room] (
    [RoomID]        INT           IDENTITY (6666, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Sports]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]   DATETIME      DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUserID] INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoomID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChatUserLog] (
    [ChatUserLogId] BIGINT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [MId]           INT      NOT NULL,
    [RoomId]        INT      NOT NULL,
    [LoggedInTime]  DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [LogOutTime]    DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ChatUserLogId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LoggedInUser] (
    [LoggedInUserID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [MId]            INT           NOT NULL,
    [RoomID]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [NickName]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Icon]           VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LoggedInUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoggedInUserID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and do the things it suggests. This question is currently not particularly answerable.

Comment: @AakashM I have added the table details in the question now. Kindly check it out and since it's a listview calling through those queries, I don't have INSERT statements over here.

Comment: And still we don´t know what your current result looks like and what the result should look like after the querys are modified. Furthermore please add information about the sql server you are running.

Answer (score 0):

While missing some information like a sample result of each query and a sample of the result you want to achieve, I can only give some basic ideas.

While you remove the `Where Sports = @Sports` part in the query the result will not be limited to a specific sport so this may fit your needs regarding the "getting results of all sports" part.

The part "top 3 alone in each of the sport" isn´t very clear to me. To which value do you want to limit the result? It might be enough to add a `LIMIT 3` to the end of your query, but as told it´s not clear to me what result you want realy want to get.

You might add some more information about your tables and sample results of your querys if this wasn´t what you want to achieve. Maybe you can give a sample of what the result should look like?

Comment: I have added the table details in the question now. Kindly check it out and you would know much more details in there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below query for getting result of top 3 alone each for all any sport from online users

**each particular sport ---- 30 day ----- Online users**

```
 select top 3 RoomId, Name,TotalUsers,UserOnline from
 (SELECT RoomId, Name,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by sports order by sports) rn,sports,
   ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) 
        From ChatUserLog 
        WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId 
        AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, 
        ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) 
        From LoggedInUser 
        WHERE RoomID = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline 
 From Room
 )s where rn<=3 and sports=@sports
 ORDER BY UserOnline DESC
```

if you want it from total users then try below query

**each particular sports ---- 30 day ----- Total users**

```
select top 3 RoomId, Name,TotalUsers,UserOnline from
(SELECT RoomId, Name,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by sports order by sports) rn,sports,
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) 
        From ChatUserLog 
        WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId 
          AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, 
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) 
        From LoggedInUser 
        WHERE RoomID = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline 
From Room
)s where rn<=3 and sports=@sports
 ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

For getting result of all sports try below query

**Individual sports ---- 30 day ----- Online users**

```
SELECT RoomId, Name, 
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) 
        From ChatUserLog 
        WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId 
          AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, 
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) 
        From LoggedInUser 
        WHERE RoomID = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline 
  From Room 
  ORDER BY UserOnline DESC
```

For Total users
**Individual sports ---- 30 day ----- Total users**

```
SELECT RoomId, Name, 
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) 
        From ChatUserLog 
        WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId 
          AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, 
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) 
        From LoggedInUser 
        WHERE RoomID = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline 
From Room 
ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it shows the error "Must declare the scalar variable "@sports".... " The Listview/Gridview which is displaying the data seems to require the Sports field.                                                                     And I only need query for the first 2 requirements and not for the last 2 (Individual sports). Thanks anyway and have a nice day ahead.